# How to define 3 average month values in a NDVI Modis time serie

Tags: r, modis

I am working with MODIS NDVI rasters from 2016. I have 365 rasters (one per day). I need to have 3 rasters per month (total = 36). First raster =  average of the first 10 days. Second raster = average of day 11 to day 20. Third raster = average of day 21 to the last day of the month (could be 28, 29, 30 or 31). My rasters are named: 2016_001, 2016_002,…, 2016_365.

Is there a way to calculate this?

I can´t stack all 365 rasters because the file will be too large (max 250 rasters).

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I do not know how to tell R that the third raster calculates until the last day of the month :(